# How to access the value of a UIControl from another UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

Beginner question. I have a UISlider on the storyboard, and in another UIView class besides the ViewController I would like to use the slider's value to change path/shape variables within the makeShape() function.

I have tried:

a) In OtherView, try to directly reference ViewController's global variable `val`. This results in "unresolved identifier"

b) In ViewController, try to assign `mySlider.value` to a variable declared in OtherView, `otherVal`. This results in "Instance member 'otherVal' cannot be used on type 'OtherView'".

Could someone please help me learn how to do this correctly?

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var val: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: UISlider!

    @IBOutlet weak var otherView: UIView!

    @IBAction func mySliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        val = CGFloat(mySlider.value)
        setOtherVal()
    }

    func setOtherVal() {
        otherView.otherVal = val
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let otherView = OtherView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))

        self.view.addSubview(otherView)
    }
}
```

OtherView.swift:

```
class OtherView: UIView {

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    var otherVal: CGFloat = 0.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        makeShape()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func makeShape() {
        let width: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width
        let height: CGFloat = self.frame.size.height

        let path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))

        let shapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer1.path = path1.cgPath
        shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)

        shapeLayer1.position = CGPoint(x: otherVal, y: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an IBOutlet instance of the `UIView` object in the view controller.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var otherView: UIView!` Like that? I put that in ViewController just below the other outlet, then tried `func setOtherVal() {otherView.otherVal = val}` and I get "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'otherVal'". Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: "I put that in ViewController just below the other outlet"  I don't see it.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: otherView.otherVal = sender.value;
otherViewmakeShape()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're trying to access the `otherVal` property in `ViewController` on the class `OtherVal` which is shared globally through the whole app, not the property on the instance of OtherVal you've created in `ViewController`.

The simplest fix here is to store the `OtherView` instance you created in `viewDidAppear` and use that property to update the view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var val: Float = 0.0
    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: UISlider!

    // Add a property to hold on to the view after you create it. 
    var otherView: OtherView?

    @IBAction func mySliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        val = mySlider.value
        setOtherVal()
    }

    func setOtherVal() {
        // `val` is a Float and `otherVal` is a `CGFloat` so we have to convert first.
        let newValue = CGFloat(self.val)
        // Use the property that's holding your view to update with the new value from the slider.
        self.otherView?.otherVal = newValue
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let otherView = OtherView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))

        // Set the property to the view you just created so you can update it later.
        self.otherView = otherView

        self.view.addSubview(otherView)
    }
}
```

Currently though it doesn't look like you're actually updating `OtherView` once the new value is set, so you'll want to do something similar there. Keep a reference to the `CAShapeLayer` you create and update the position when `otherVal` changes.

Also note `viewDidAppear` can be called multiple times throughout a view controller's life cycle. If you only want to add the view once, you should use `viewDidLoad` which will guarantee you have a freshly created `self.view` to work with.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, you can also set up a custom view in the storyboard / nib and create an outlet. Right now it doesn't look like your code is set up to work with that though.